# On Objective-C delegates, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, delegates

If my `UIView` (`MyUIView`) declares and `@synthesize`(s)

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
```

and `MyController` is declared as

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

and the following is true (inside MyController)

```
if ([self.view isKindOfClass:[MyUIView class]]){
    NSLog(@"yes");          // We see this
}
```

**Why is the following a problem?**

```
 self.view.delegate = self; // Does not see "delegate"
```

Meanwhile, if i manually create an instance of MyView, it works:

```
MyView *c = [MyView new];    
c.delegate = self;          // works fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `view` property of `UIViewController` is declared as `UIView *`, and `UIView` doesn't have a `delegate` property. Note that property (and method) lookup by the compiler is *not* dynamic, as it's done at compile time.

Use

```
((MyUIView *)(self.view)).delegate = self;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because just by checking that the `view` property is a `MyUIView` does not automatically cast it to one.

You want something like this:

```
if ([self.view isKindOfClass:[MyUIView class]]) {
    MyUIView *myView = (MyUIView*)self.view;
    myView.delegate = self;
}
```

Notice how after checking, I create a variable of type `MyUIView*` which the compiler will then be able to "see" the `delegate` property on it. It's all about types :-).

Answer (score 1):

`[self.view isKindOfClass:[MyUIView class]]` is a run-time check and can determine what kind of object has actually been assigned to `view`.  On the other hand, the compiler is complaining because it doesn't have that information and only knows that `view` is some kind of `UIView`.

Use a cast on `self.view` to tell the compiler that you know what's going to be stored there.